# Debian Kernel Update frozen at 99% - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: debian, kernel, upgrade

I am using Debian 11 Stable. `gnome-software` notified that an update requiring a restart is available. It was an 'OS Update'. `linux-image-amd64` was to be updated from `5.10.162-1` to `5.10.178-3` and `linux-image-5.10.0-22-amd64` was to be installed. I clicked 'Restart & Update' as usual. However the offline update got stuck. In less than 5 minutes it reached 99% but never finished. I am still on the `A start job is running for Update the operating system whilst offline (2h 30min 37s / no limit)` dialogue.

Is it safe to kill the power? Is my system damaged? How should I troubleshoot? If I am forced to shutdown, how should I recover the kernel?